# Calculate right ascension in Zenith at this moment in my location

Tags: ascension

I've been searching on Internet about how to calculate which RA is in zenith at a given location in a given time but I haven't find anything (or maybe I don't know how to search).

Using my star finder I have not draw any conclusion.

How can I calculate which RA is on zenith on a given location in a given time?

Comment: Maybe here: https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kdeedu/kstars/ai-sidereal.html. Note the Right Ascension of the Zenith: it is exactly the same as your Local Sidereal Time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right ascension at Zenith should always be your local sidereal time.